# How can I add missing DOS commands to DOSBox?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, freedos, dosbox

I am trying to execute .bat file in the [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/):

It starts with the following lines:

```
echo off
cls
if exist %1:\BLA\z.exe goto custom      
if not exist d:\BLA\z.exe goto error
APPEND d:\BLA;d:\BLA\SUBFOLDER /X:ON /PATH:ON
goto start
```

And it results in:

> Illegal command: APPEND.

As I understand the issue is that DOSBox does not support APPEND command.

---

How can I add missing DOS commands to the DOSBox? Can I somehow extract them from [FreeDos](https://www.freedos.org/) project?
Is it possible to extract required file / files, without installing FreeDos in virtual machine (and then copy-pasting required files)?

Comment: [Append](http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/Append) was dropped in FreeDos.

Comment: @harrymc I was not aware. What is the suggested way of rewriting batch files that contains calls to Append?

Comment: could you just simply add `d:\bla;d:\bla\subfolder` to the path? as in `path=%path%;d:\bla;d:\bla\subfolder` ?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I've tried to do so, before creating this question, but application after starting is not responding. Thus I am afraid I made a mistake and I prefer to have `append` command instead. - There are few batch files that calls append commands (combined with if statements) before running the `exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download different versions of Microsoft DOS from winworldpc.com [here](https://winworldpc.com/product/ms-dos/622).  You can then install/extract `append.exe` and copy it to your DOSBox.  I would *expect* it to work, but not sure.  There is not harm in trying.

On a side note, *technically* this would be copyright infringement.  However, I cant imagine Microsoft isnt aware of this popular site that has been online for almost 20 years.  I assume they just dont care about unsupported software this old being copied.

Comment: Will it be possibile to instead compile `append` from FreeDos project? Od even simplier - find somehow and old version of FreeDos With append and copy it to the DosBox? Or maybe DosBox team would consider adding append to their project?

Comment: @matandked I dont know if FreeDOS has append.  I havent used it in ages.  If DOSBox doesnt have append now, I doubt they will add it.  However, you can definitely get it from MS-DOS from the site I linked to in my answer.

Comment: I have not tested it, but I've found `append` listed here: https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.3/official/report.html

Comment: Direct download link to `append` from FreeDos: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/repositories/1.3/base/append.zip

Comment: And on another page, I've found that to use append with DosBox i should `ver set 6 22`